# Trying to insert only unique row into new table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to insert only unique values into a table but it is not working. There is only one value of LastDownload in the Securities table for all 6000 rows.  But in my query I get over 6000 duplications of that value in @Temp. I want only one value.  What am I missing?

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE ( Info VARCHAR( 256 ) )

INSERT INTO @Temp
SELECT LastDownLoad
FROM Securities AS S
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM @Temp AS T WHERE T.Info = S.LastDownLoad )
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is overly simplistic... but... it seems to fit...

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE ( Info VARCHAR( 256 ) )

    INSERT INTO @Temp
    SELECT Distinct LastDownLoad
    FROM Securities
```

Answer (score 2):

Put both answers together, and you get the complete answer:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE ( Info VARCHAR( 256 ) )

INSERT INTO @Temp
SELECT DISTINCT LastDownLoad
FROM Securities AS S
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM @Temp AS T WHERE T.Info = S.LastDownLoad )
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using `distinct`?

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE ( Info VARCHAR( 256 ) )

INSERT INTO @Temp
SELECT LastDownLoad
FROM Securities AS S
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT DISTINCT * FROM @Temp AS T WHERE T.Info = S.LastDownLoad )
```